# I have an issue when trying to add class to image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the code:

```js
$(function()
{
  $('.sign1').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('good');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 menu-item">
        <div class="front">
        <a href="main.html"><img class="center-block sign1" src="images/sign1.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's supposed to add the class 'good' when clicking the image with class 'sign1'
but that never happens.

what's wrong with my code please?

Comment: You have no element with a class of `sign1`.

Comment: I turned your HTML/JS code into a snippet, which also illustrates what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code works fine if you remove the link `<a>` surrounding the `<img>` element.

after jquery adds the `good` class to the image, the click even bubbles up to its parent `<a>` and this directs the browser to the new address: `main.html`.

so you won't have the time to see the change i suppose.

Comment: Thanks Tang. It worked fine after removing the (a) tag, but that didn't solve my main problem. I need to be redirected to main.html after clicking and adding the (good) class. Is there any code in jQuery that opens a link or page after click?

Comment: @HanyTaha, What is the practical use of adding a class if you're navigating away???

Comment: I agree with @trincot

Answer (score 0):

You can code like below

```
var targetImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
targetImg.classList.add("mystyle");
```